# クライアント証明書の方がAPI Keyよりもセキュアなのでしょうか？

Tags: api, security, ssl

２つのシステムのAPI連携方法を検討しています。API Keyよりもクライアント証明書の方がセキュアそうに感じているのですが、実際はどうなのでしょうか？API Key、クライアント証明書ともに攻撃者に流出、推測したら情報流出のリスクがあるのでセキュリティ強度は同じと考えるべきでしょうか？